# Unsupported operation exception in thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have made a thread for certain process, and I am running this thread with Progress Dialog simultaneously. when process complete, Progress Dialog will dismiss. until this there is no problem but when user will press back button of phone two times, activity will destroy and my process should be stop. so I have stopped thread in onDestroy(). but app is crashing at `mt.stop()` my code and error log is as bellow. please give me any solution and also if possible I want reason behind this.
  Using flag, process will check for stop only at start of each iteration. and I want to stop process eminently.

code

```
Button b;
ProgressDialog pd = null;
MyThread mt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "one", "two", true, true);
    mt = new MyThread();
    mt.start();
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // assume this loop is my process.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.v("log_tag", "" + i);
        }
        Log.v("log_tag", "process COmplited");
        pd.dismiss();
        super.run();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.v("log_tag", "OnDestroy");
    pd.dismiss();
    mt.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

error in log cat;

```
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at com.example.threaddemo.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:53)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-09 17:26:45.313: E/global(594):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756862/how-to-stop-a-thread

Comment: Reading the plain error message shows the solution: Don't use the deprecated stop method!

Comment: Thread stop method is deprecated and "Deprecated thread methods are not supported"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer my solution at:
[android kill specific thread on action bar event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311198/android-kill-specific-thread-on-action-bar-event)

The solution of using a TimerTask instead of the thread can server your purponse better and more optimized.

Even the cancellation would work :)

P.S: It also has information why `stop` is not working for you.